# Vector Drawables work out of the box on Android 4+

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, androidx

I use vector drawables on Android 4+ from XML and code without any issues.

Setup: Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1, Android Studio 3.2.1, Gradle 4.10.1, android-x support library with Jetifier on.

Example usage:

- `app:srcCompat="@drawable/some_vector_drawable"`
- `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/some_vector_drawable"`
- `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.some_vector_drawable)`

Many official or less official blogs or stack overflow posts mention usage of:

- `android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in `build.gradle`
- and/or: `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` from code

but my vector drawables run everywhere fine without any of these.

Is there any official, final documentation on this? Are these flags necessary?

The only thing I notice is this warning in Android Studio, which I ignore:

> to use vector drawable compat you need to set defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without:**

> android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

in `build.gradle`, PNGs are generated for each vector drawable and become part of resulting .apk file.

**With** the above flag on, following is possible:

- `app:srcCompat="@drawable/some_vector_drawable"` in layout xml
- `android:icon="@drawable/some_vector_drawable"` in menu xml
- `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_vector_drawable)` in code

  (but vector drawable needs to be a single vector (i.e.: start with `<vector`))
- getting VectorDrawable from code:

  Drawable vectorDrawable = [VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, R.drawable.some_vector_drawable, null)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat#create(android.content.res.Resources,%20int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme))

  This can then be used as regular drawable (e.g.: `imageView.setImageDrawable(vectorDrawable)`)

**With both:**

> android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
>
> & AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)

together, `VectorDrawables` work pretty much as if they were native on Android 4+. 
However, Google warns that using [AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(boolean)) may cause memory issues or issues with `Configuration` object (I have not experienced any).

Answer (score 1):

The [Vector drawables overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources#vector-drawables-backward-solution) recommends it, but doesn't say it's needed.

It also says this:

> Android Studio 1.4 introduced limited compatibility support for vector drawables by generating PNG files at build time.

It's unclear, and the [Release Notes for 1.4](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#older-releases) don't actually mention much about vector Drawables. However, it seems to be saying that, when you don't tell Gradle that you want to use the support library, it will instead generate density-dependent PNGs for each vector, and presumably use those on older devices instead of the vectors.

If that's true, you really should be using the support library. Generating a PNG for each DPI is going to bloat your app size quite a bit. I'm pretty sure the support library generates PNGs at runtime for devices that can't support vectors, meaning the APK stays small.